# Kong - random Certificate has expired

Tags: kong

I'm using Kong version 2.3.3 with SSL. I config the SSL by setting it in side kong.conf like this,

ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt
ssl_cert_key = /etc/ssl/private.key

Previously, everything worked perfectly. Buy when the SSL certificate was expired and I renew them with the new one. I have a new SSL set up inside kong.conf like this,

ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/2022/ssl_certificate.crt
ssl_cert_key = /etc/ssl/2022/private.key

After the update. I get a random error  **Certificate has expired**. Sometimes it works but sometimes it throw this expire error. I really don't know how to solve this.

Please help.